# How do you change the height of the TTTableMoreButton?

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

Is there a way to change the height of the TTTableMoreButton without creating a new class ItemClass for TTTableMoreButton and return that class in the function

```
- (Class)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellClassForObject:(id)object
```

Thanks a mil. Do let me know if it is not possible.

Cheers,
Mickey

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that you won't be changing the height of the `TTTableMoreButton`, but will rather be changing the height of the `TTTableMoreButtonCell` that is associated with the `TTTableMoreButton`. The correct way to do what I think you're trying to achieve is to create a subclass of both `TTTableMoreButton` and `TTTableMoreButtonCell`, override the

```
+ (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)object;
```

function in your `TTTableMoreButtonCell` subclass, and then inside of your data source, be sure to map between the two classes as you yourself mentioned like:

```
- (Class)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellClassForObject:(id)object {
  if ([object isKindOfClass:[CustomItem class]]) {
    return [CustomItemCell class];
  } else {
    return [super tableView:tableView cellClassForObject:object];
  }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Great answer. Also a great design of Three20, conforming to the Open-Closed Principle.